# SAXON 9: Error Listener's fatalError exception never bubbles during TransformerFactory.newFactory() call

Tags: java, xml, exception, saxon

In the case that a contained XML file is malformed (i.e. lacking a tag closure somewhere), I need a TransformerException to bubble up in the case of a fatalError. Counter to the spec, the error is completely suppressed. This is a pure XML problem, not an XSL one.

```
try {
    TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    MyErrorListener errorListener = new MyErrorListener();
    factory.setErrorListener(errorListener);
    StreamSource ss = new StreamSource(new StringReader(badXslText), "file:" + xslPath);
    Transformer xf = factory.newTransformer(ss); // This is where MyErrorListener.fatalError below happens.. but that never bubbles up for some reason
    System.out.println("Nothing went wrong!");  // Yes it effing did!
} catch (TransformerException e) {
    //Why isn't this getting hit?
    String message = e.getMessage();
    throw new Exception("Problem during transform. "+message);
}
```

Here's the barebones error listener (with a couple methods removed for brevity):

```
public static class MyErrorListener implements ErrorListener {
    private ArrayList<String> messages = new ArrayList<String>();
    public void fatalError(TransformerException e) throws TransformerException {
        messages.add(e);
        throw e; //This is reached, but never caught on the top level
    }
    public List<String> getMessages() {
        return messages;
    }
}
```

I'm nearly pulling my hair out at this one.

Comment: I've got a unit test essentially identical to this and it works for me. Could you expand it to a completely self-contained test (include the full input files, and the full Java module including all includes, etc) and say which specific version of Saxon you are using: "Saxon 9" is not very specific.

Comment: I'll get together a test, but it's looking like this is an issue having to do with a double-nested xsl includes, i.e. a situation where a file includes a file which includes another file that has a missing closure or similar. Not sure why the innermost xsl wouldn't make the newTransformer call bomb out, even though it still logs the error.

Comment: So your comment about the version was relevant--this was a bug in an older version of saxon. I was using version 9.3, which still had the exact problem you outlined here: https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/1866  I updated saxon and the issue's gone. Thanks for all your work

Comment: And thanks for reporting the diagnosis.